# Do Hindus believe that one can see god after death as per Advaitha?

Tags: gods, advaita

Can we see god after death as per Advaitha.

Advaitha says that we can see the god when we went into deep medidation state, then what about death? so as death is not that deep meditation state, then we cant see the god even after death? We cant even see Lord Yama after death?

This birth and death cycle keep on rotating without the appearcance of god to a common person, then how he realizes that there is a god who can pull him out of  this cycle?

Comment: What Dvaita or Advaita has to do sith it?

Comment: Good question @user2225190

Comment: As per Advaita, Self is God(Aham Brahmasmi-I am Brahman) but Maya i.e. world and body does not exist.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadasiva_Brahmendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an excerpt from the [teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.](https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/instructions/)

> The mind is a wondrous power residing in the Self. It causes all
>   thoughts to arise. Apart from thoughts, there is no such thing as
>   mind. Therefore, thought is the nature of mind. Apart from thoughts,
>   there is no independent entity called the world. In deep sleep there
>   are no thoughts, and there is no world. In the states of waking and
>   dream, there are thoughts, and there is a world also.
>
> That which rises as ‘I’ in the body is the mind. If one inquires as to
>   where in the body the thought ‘I’ rises first, one would discover that
>   it rises in the Heart. That is the place of the mind’s origin. Even if
>   one thinks constantly ‘I’, ‘I’, one will be led to that place. Of all
>   the thoughts that arise in the mind, the ‘I’ thought is the first. It
>   is only after the rise of the “I-thought” that other thoughts occur.
>
> ***The thought ‘who am I?’ will destroy all other thoughts, and like the
>   stick used for stirring the funeral pyre, it will itself be burnt up
>   in the end.*** Then, there will be ***Self-realization***. When other thoughts
>   arise, one should not pursue them but should diligently inquire: ‘To
>   whom do they occur?’ It does not matter how many thoughts arise. As
>   each thought arises, one should inquire with alertness, “To whom has
>   this thought arisen?” The answer that would emerge would be “to me”.
>   Thereupon if one inquires “Who am I?” the mind will go back to its
>   source; and the thought that arose will subside.
>
> With repeated practice in this manner, the mind will develop the power
>   to stay in its source. When the mind that is subtle goes out through
>   the brain and the sense organs, ***the gross names and forms appear; when
>   it stays in the heart, the names and forms disappear.*** Not letting the
>   mind go out, but retaining it in the Heart is what is called
>   “inwardness”. Letting the mind go out of the Heart is known as
>   “externalisation”. Thus, when the mind stays in the Heart, the ‘I’
>   which is the source of all thoughts will go, and ***the Self which ever
>   exists will shine.***

---

Coming to the question - ***Can we see god after death as per Advaitha?***, we have to understand that having visions of various forms of God like, Sri Rama, Vishnu, Shiva, Shakti, Ganapati, etc, is the result of severe austerities on the part of the spiritual aspirant, at some point of time, before Self Realisation.

So having vision of some form of God, ***is not the finality***. If that was the case why Sri Ramakrishna continued his austeries, even after having the vision of Kali?

**Self Realisation** in other words is called the attaining of the state of **advaita** or **non-duality**.  When this stage has finally been achieved, where is the question of worrying about having vision of the God after death?